# Is there any way to get GDE (Global Directory Editor) Raw unformatted values as output

Tags: mumps, gtm-database

I'm writing a utility in JavaScript to interact with GTM's GDE(Global Directory Editor). One of the things it needs to accomplish is to run the GDE SHOW -ALL command and get a listing of all information in the Global Directory. However, SHOW command formats the values for display in terminal environment, which is unusable for my purpose, without extensive parsing.

Does anyone know of any ways to get the the Global Directory information unformatted(perhaps in key-value pairs/zwrite format)?
If GDE can't provide that, are there any ways or algorithms to read the actual Global Directory File, to get that information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GDE has a command that prints out the list of commands to regenerate the GDE. That can be easily parsed.

```
> $gtm_dist/mumps -run GDE show -command -file="gde.cmd"
> head -6 gde.cmd

TEMPLATE -REGION -NOAUTODB
TEMPLATE -REGION -COLLATION_DEFAULT=0
TEMPLATE -REGION -EPOCHTAPER
TEMPLATE -REGION -NOINST_FREEZE_ON_ERROR
TEMPLATE -REGION -JOURNAL=(ALLOCATION=2048,AUTOSWITCHLIMIT=8386560,BEFORE_IMAGE,BUFFER_SIZE=2312,EXTENSION=2048)
> tail -6 gde.cmd
ADD -REGION DEFAULT -DYNAMIC_SEGMENT=DEFAULT
!
ADD -SEGMENT DEFAULT -FILE_NAME="mumps.dat"
!
LOCKS -REGION=DEFAULT
!
```

Note that "Template" corresponds to configuration that is common to all/most regions. Any exception is logged under the individual region/segment.

Also note that the latest GT.M release (V7.0-000) removed ^%DSEWRAP.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `^%DSEWRAP` against the main global file.

E.g.: https://github.com/shabiel/Kernel-GTM/blob/master/Kernel/Routines/ZISHGUX.m#L216

--Sam

Comment: Thank you Sam. This seems to take care of most of the things I needed.